# unable to install Silverlight on Visual Studio 2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have installed Visual Studio 2010 and applied SP1.
I am unable to install Silverlight 4 tools to start a silverlight project. 
I rebooted the machine after installing Visual Studio 2010 and after applying the SP1, yet I get this error shown below. It seems that Silverlight does not detect Visual Studio on the machine. How to fix that?

[image: silverlight 4 tools install error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is misleading.

I had to install the Silverlight SDK before installing the Silverlight tools, and that way works fine.